# Using a present tense verb in an "if" clause, followed by the main clause

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Is it possible to have a present tense verb in a sentence like this:

> If you resign now, you'd feel sorry later.

Or must you always follow the second conditional format, arriving at a sentence like this:

> If you resigned now, you'd feel sorry later.

My goal is not to necessarily to produce a second conditional sentence, but rather to see whether the first sentence is acceptable, whether interpreted as a second conditional or not.  It seems acceptable; what explanation is there for this?

Comment: As soon as you start slinging around terms like “second conditional”, you have left the path of wisdom.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

> If you resign now, you'll feel sorry later.

Since you're predicting the future, you use the ordinary future tense.

You use *would* with a counter-factual:

> If you had resigned yesterday, you'd feel sorry today.

Comment: Your authority for such a bold statement ('It should be')? As Matt Gutting has said, 'What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer[:] one that you can support with authoritative references.' The fact that there are different views needs to be taken into consideration.

Comment: Speaking English as a native for 50+ years.

Comment: I have the advantage then, Sir.

Answer (score 2):

According to [EnglishPage](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/presentconditional.html) [modified slightly]:

> **Present Real Conditional**
>
> FORM
>
> [If / When ... Simple Present ..., ... Simple Present ...]
>
> USE: The Present Real Conditional is used to talk about what you
>   normally do in real-life situations.
>
> eg: If [/When] I go to a friend's house for dinner, I usually take a bottle of
>   wine.
>
> **Present Unreal Conditional**
>
> FORM
>
> [If ... Simple Past ..., ... would + bare infinitive ...]
>
> USE: The Present Unreal Conditional is used to talk about what you
>   would generally do in imaginary situations [including situations under
>   serious consideration].
>
> eg: If I won the lottery, I would buy a house.

[Note the indication of sequentiality; buying the house is in the future wrt winning the lottery, though this construction is classified as the 'Present Unreal Conditional'.] This would indicate the choice

> If you resigned now, you'd feel sorry later.

here. However, I suspect that

> If you resign now, you'll feel sorry later.

is used just about as frequently.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly not true that you must always follow the prototypical second conditional format, namely past tense in the *if-clause* and *would + infinitive* in the main clause.

It is worth quoting Michael Lewis in *The English Verb* (p148) to see why this is the case:

> It is the verb phrase not the sentence which is the fundamental unit
>   requiring analysis. Certain combinations are, for semantic reasons,
>   highly frequent, while others are less frequent or even impossible. ...
>
> A particular misunderstanding frequently arises in the teaching of
>   so-called conditional sentences. It is common to teach three basic
>   kinds. ...
>
> If students are taught only the first, second and third conditionals,
>   they will know only a small, admittedly highly frequent, sub-set of
>   the possibilities. It is not necessary to teach the fourth
>   conditional, the fifth conditional, etc., but it is important to
>   recognise that the possibility arises from the meaning of the
>   individual clauses ... . The explanation of the use of a form in a
>   conditional sentence is exactly the same as that of its occurrence in
>   any other utterance. The underlying principle behind this is that each
>   main verb phrase is treated independently.

So on this basis we can speculate that the present tense is used in *If you resign now*, because the '*you*' may indeed be seriously thinking of resigning. Using the past tense *If you resigned now* could imply that the speaker feels this is a more remote possibility. Similarly, the use of *will* in the main clause (*you will feel sorry later*) makes it a stronger prediction than *you'd feel sorry later*.

There are many Google hits for this combination of tenses with the string "*if you do that you would*". For example:

> If you do that, you would be surprised how competitive we could be.
>
> If you do that, you would have no problems — but if you shut the car
>   off with the radio on, it would draw the battery down over a week's
>   time.
>
> If you do that, you would be caught-up in the chicken and egg
>   question.
>
> If you do that, you would exceed your standard quota of three felonies
>   a day.
>
> If you do that you would not able to use ffmpeg in other software.
>
> And if you do that, you would have enough to pay for something better.
>
> If you do that you would be compromising with reality.

Answer (score 1):

These two sentences mean different things.

**If you resign now, you will regret it.

If you resigned now, you would regret it.**

The first says this:  if x happens, y will follow. It is a prediction. The second sentence is less a prediction than a contemplation of a hypothetical scenario.

The real-world context determines which formulation to use.

Let's say you are an advisor to a person holding political office, and that person is about to go on live TV in a few minutes and resign publicly. You might grab your last chance to dissuade them and say *If you resign now, you will regret it.* But if you are discussing a course of action with that person, carefully weighing options, assessing costs and benefits, you might say *If you resigned now, you would regret it*.