# Tense Consistency and Conditional Verb tense

Tags: tenses, conditionals

I had just told someone that someone couldn't join our study group because he didn't have a good enough foundation.

As a reply, someone wished to say, "If he joins / joined our study group, he would get better at English as time goes / went on."

My real question is on the last half. **Should it be "goes on" or "went on."** I know "would" has many uses other than it's ability to express the past tense, but I am unsure if it is always necessary to keep accompanying verbs in the past tense as well.

Thank you.

Comment: *If he **joins**, he **will** improve as time **passes*** arguably implies speaker thinks this is a distinct possibility. Or use the "subjunctive" past tense - perhaps implying greater separation from the real world, as in "speaker thinks it's unlikely he'll join" - *If he **joined**, he **would** improve as time **passed***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a present tense verb in an "if" clause, followed by the main clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217732/using-a-present-tense-verb-in-an-if-clause-followed-by-the-main-clause)

Comment: @FumbleFingers as usual *not* fumbling the grammar. I would suggest also the second *someone* in your example sentence become *someone else* to make clear it's a different someone (or say "person A" and "person B", for example).

Comment: @WillCrawford: Good point about *someone **else***